# Не получается сбросить пароль MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Ввел эти команды:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Вывело:

```
[1] 4617
gdmoonpy@gdmoonpypc:~$ 2019-08-14T11:37:19.700360Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-08-14T11:37:19.706603Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-08-14T11:37:19.716231Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

Пишу:

```
mysql -uroot
```

Выводит:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Почему я не могу зайти в MySQL?

Comment: Ну оно ж вроде вменяемо пишет - нет каталога для создания файла сокета. Создай... ну или подключись по IP через локалхост.

Comment: @Akina папка есть

Comment: Значит, нет прав. Не с потолка же сервер взял, что он этой папки не видит...

Comment: Сделайте через добавление `skip-grant-tables` в раздел `[mysqld]`  файла конфигурации `my.cnf` и перезапустите mysql-сервис

Comment: @Jigius такого раздела там нет...

Comment: добавьте две строки: `[mysqld]`, `skip-grant-tables`

Comment: @Jigius не помогло

Comment: версия ubunt'ы какая?

Comment: @Jigius 18.04 LTS

Comment: смотри файл `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` на предмет раздела `[mysqld]` и добавляй в него `skip-grant-tables`

Comment: @Jigius все равно не помогло

Comment: перезапустили mysqld?

Comment: @Jigius да, перезапустил